# Sorting A Listbox Numerically VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sorting, listbox, listboxitem

I have a list of numbers in a windows form list box that I have built in VSTO Visual Studio 2012. I am writing in vb.net

The list sorts alphabetically and I need it to sort numerically.

ie currently sorts like     1,10,100,2,3,4
I need it to sort like      1,2,3,4,10,100

I found this found online which works (up until the last point).

```
Dim MyItems = (From item In HardCodeListBox.Items Order By CInt(item.text) Select _
   item).ToArray

HardCodeListBox.Items.Clear()
HardCodeListBox.Items.AddRange(MyItems) ' This Does Not Work For Me
```

The message I am getting is "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]'."

Sorry - I am a bit green in VSTO and don't know how to fix this.

The big picture of what I am trying to do is sort a listbox by clicking the header.
I want it to alternate each time the user clicks it, ie ascending, then descending. then ascending with each subsequent click.

The list box items are checked (some are, some are not depending on the users choices), I need to retain these selections on sorting.

Any help would be extremely helpful!

Comment: You're trying to assign an array of objects to what should be an enumerable of ListViewItems.  You know that's what the objects are, but the compiler doesn't.  So you must cast your array to an array of ListViewItems.

Comment: ...and a ListBox does not accept ListViewItems, so you must be working with a ListView.  And if that is case, then the LV support sorting via methods.  `myListView.Sorting = Ascending ... myListView.Sort`.  Since they are numbers you will likely need to use the `ListViewItemSorter` prop with a ICompare sorter